# Show it has maximum

Tags: calculus

Let twice differentiable function $f: [0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) =0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. If $f(x)$ has a unique inflection point on $x=a >0$ and $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=0$ prove that exists $b\in(0,a)$ in which $f(x)$ obtains its maximum value.

So far, I've found that $f'(\xi)=0$ for a $\xi\in(0,a)$ and I proved that it can't have a max on $x≥a$. Is it enough to show that $f$ is concave down in this interval?

Comment: $f''<0$ would indeed be sufficient. I'd argue that because of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ and $f(x)>0$, you'd have $f'' > 0$ on $(a,\infty)$, since $f'$ would be negative and have to be increasing towards zero.

Comment: It is sufficient that you've shown that no point in $[a, \infty)$ is a maximum. As a continuous function $f$ has to have some maximum $b$ on $[0,a]$, and since neither $a$ nor $0$ can be that maximimum, and there can be no higher maximum on $[a, \infty)$, that $b \in (0,a)$ must be the maximum over all $[0,\infty)$.